# Can I use ant war task to export a war built with Maven?

Tags: maven, ant, build

Im using eclipse and maven for my day to day development, which works fine. However I need a specialized war created when its time to export to send over to production, which includes things like minifying and combining js/css etc, separating out static resources for apache rather than tomcat etc.

I tried the maven plugin route but it was a hassle, I'd rather write a simply ant script to export when necessary. I'm using the ant war task, but the exported war contains everything except my WEB-INF/libs folder, which is blank. Does anyone know a way to make the script work with all the libs that maven looks up? This is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="war" basedir=".">

    <property name="builder" value="Me" />
    <property name="project-name" value="${ant.project.name}" />
    <property name="war-file-name" value="${project-name}.war" />
    <property name="source-directory" value="src/main/java" />
    <property name="classes-directory" value="target/classes" />
    <property name="web-directory" value="src/main/webapp" />
    <property name="web-xml-file" value="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
    <property name="build-directory" value="/" />

    <tstamp prefix="build-info">
        <format property="current-date" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy" locale="en" />
        <format property="current-time" pattern="hh:mm:ss a z" locale="en" />
    </tstamp>

    <target name="war" depends="">
        <mkdir dir="${build-directory}" />
        <delete file="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" />
        <war warfile="${build-directory}/${war-file-name}" webxml="${web-xml-file}">
            <classes dir="${classes-directory}" />
            <fileset dir="${web-directory}">
                <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${builder}" />
                <attribute name="Built-On" value="${build-info.current-date}" />
                <attribute name="Built-At" value="${build-info.current-time}" />
            </manifest>
        </war>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use ant scripts like this. This will not work in particular if you a release via Maven. The better things seemed to me you explain what you exactly need to do and how your targeting war must look like and may be there are ideas how to solve that in a Maven way. (one thought on that maven-assembly-plugin)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [maven ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/) for this.  I have not tried this, but from [the examples](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html), something like this should work...

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
  <pom file="pom.xml"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
<copy todir="${webapp.output}/WEB-INF/lib">
  <fileset refid="dependency.fileset" />
  <!-- This mapper strips off all leading directory information -->
  <mapper type="flatten" />
</copy>
```